# prism how to find the view which in the views folder's child folder

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows-store-apps, prism

I am studying the prism in windows store app. I got a problem. I have many views, and i want to separate them into different folders. but the problem is that the NavigationService cannot find them.The instruction book say that all the view show put into the views folder,then the navigationservice can navigate to them by using navigationservice.navigate("main",null),but if the view is not in the root of the views folder the navigationservice cannot find them

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! To make it easier for people to answer, you may have to give more detail about the problem you're having. Code or screenshots, as well as a more detailed explanation of the problem and what you've already tried, can help.

Answer (score 5):

NavigationService looks for Views and ViewModels according to conventions. All Views must be in "Views" folder and ViewModels must be in "ViewModels" folder. If id doesn't suitable for you can do the following:

1. Add the following class to you project:

   ```
   public class ViewViewModelTypeResolver
   {
       private const string ViewNameSuffix = "Page"; // You can change this View name suffix
       private const string ViewModelNameSuffix = "ViewModel"; // You can change this ViewModel name suffix

       private readonly Lazy<Dictionary<string, Type>> _uiAssemblyExportedTypes;

       private Dictionary<string, Type> UiAssemblyExportedTypes
       {
           get { return _uiAssemblyExportedTypes.Value; }
       }

       public ViewViewModelTypeResolver(Type typeFromUiAssembly)
       {
           _uiAssemblyExportedTypes = new Lazy<Dictionary<string, Type>>(() => GetUiAssemblyExportedTypes(typeFromUiAssembly));
       }

       public Type GetViewType(string viewTypeName)
       {
           return UiAssemblyExportedTypes[viewTypeName];
       }

       public Type GetViewModelType(Type viewType)
       {
           var pageNameWithoutSuffix = viewType.Name.Remove(viewType.Name.LastIndexOf(ViewNameSuffix, StringComparison.Ordinal));
           var viewModelName = String.Concat(pageNameWithoutSuffix, ViewModelNameSuffix);
           return UiAssemblyExportedTypes[viewModelName];
       }


       private static Dictionary<string, Type> GetUiAssemblyExportedTypes(Type typeFromUiAssembly)
       {
           return typeFromUiAssembly.GetTypeInfo().Assembly.ExportedTypes.ToDictionary(type => type.Name, type => type, StringComparer.Ordinal);
       }
   }
   ```
2. Add ViewViewModelTypeResolver to App constructor:

   ```
   public App()
   {
       var mainPage = typeof(MainPage); // Any of pages from your solution. Pay attention that the resolver will be able to resolve Views and ViewModels that locates in the same project as specified page.
       _viewViewModelTypeResolver = new ViewViewModelTypeResolver(mainPage);
   }
   ```
3. As you use Prism I assume that you inherit your App class from `MvvmAppBase`. If so you should override `GetPageType` method:

   ```
       protected override Type GetPageType(string pageToken)
       {
           return _viewViewModelTypeResolver.GetViewType(pageToken);
       }
   ```
4. Then add `SetDefaultViewTypeToViewModelTypeResolver` in `OnInitializeAsync` method:

   ```
   protected override async Task OnInitializeAsync(IActivatedEventArgs args)
   {
       // Your initialization code

       ViewModelLocationProvider.SetDefaultViewTypeToViewModelTypeResolver(GetViewModelType);

       // Your initialization code
   }

   private Type GetViewModelType(Type pageType)
   {
       return _viewViewModelTypeResolver.GetViewModelType(pageType);
   }
   ```

Now you can navigate to any of your pages even when they are separated into different folders.

Answer (score 0):

Great answer from Alexander.Ermolaev. I wanted to extend his class to suit my needs. I don't like to make all my ViewModels public. I also didn't want to keep a dictionary of all types when all we really need are the types of Views and ViewModels. This will find all Views that inherit from UserControl since ViewModelLocator will work with UserControls as well as Pages. This will find all ViewModels that inherit from a base view model class, typically ViewModelBase from Prism.

```
sealed class ViewViewModelTypeResolver
{
    private readonly Assembly _assembly;
    private readonly Type _baseViewModelType;
    private readonly string _viewNameSuffix;
    private readonly string _viewModelNameSuffix;
    private readonly Lazy<Dictionary<string, Type>> _views;
    private readonly Lazy<Dictionary<string, Type>> _viewModels;

    private Dictionary<string, Type> Views => _views.Value;
    private Dictionary<string, Type> ViewModels => _viewModels.Value;

    /// <summary>
    /// Resolves Views and ViewModels.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="typeFromUiAssembly">Use any type from the UI Assembly.</param>
    /// <param name="baseViewModelType">All view models need to inherit from this type.</param>
    /// <param name="viewNameSuffix">Prism convention is to name your views with a Page suffix.</param>
    /// <param name="viewModelNameSuffix">Prism convention is name your viewmodels with a ViewModel suffix.</param>
    public ViewViewModelTypeResolver(Type typeFromUiAssembly, Type baseViewModelType, string viewNameSuffix = "Page", string viewModelNameSuffix = "ViewModel")
    {
        _baseViewModelType = baseViewModelType;
        _viewNameSuffix = viewNameSuffix;
        _viewModelNameSuffix = viewModelNameSuffix;
        _assembly = typeFromUiAssembly.GetTypeInfo().Assembly;

        _views = new Lazy<Dictionary<string, Type>>(GetViews);
        _viewModels = new Lazy<Dictionary<string, Type>>(GetViewModels);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets a View type for the given name.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="viewTypeName">Name of the view without the suffix.</param>
    public Type GetViewType(string viewTypeName)
    {
        var pageName = string.Concat(viewTypeName, _viewNameSuffix);
        return this.Views[pageName];
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets a ViewModel for the given view type.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="viewType">Type of view.</param>
    public Type GetViewModelType(Type viewType)
    {
        var viewModelName = string.Concat(viewType.Name, _viewModelNameSuffix);
        return this.ViewModels[viewModelName];
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets all the View types by finding all types that inherit from Page and are defined in the UI Assembly.
    /// </summary>
    private Dictionary<string, Type> GetViews()
    {
        var types = _assembly.DefinedTypes.Where(type => !type.IsAbstract && type.IsSubclassOf(typeof(UserControl)));

        return types.ToDictionary(typeInfo => typeInfo.Name, typeInfo => typeInfo.AsType(), StringComparer.Ordinal);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets all the ViewModel types by finding all types that inherit from a base ViewModel type defined in the UI Assembly.
    /// </summary>
    private Dictionary<string, Type> GetViewModels()
    {
        var types = _assembly.DefinedTypes.Where(type => !type.IsAbstract && type.IsSubclassOf(_baseViewModelType));

        return types.ToDictionary(typeInfo => typeInfo.Name, typeInfo => typeInfo.AsType(), StringComparer.Ordinal);
    }
}
```

Usage from App.cs:

```
private readonly ViewViewModelTypeResolver _viewViewModelTypeResolver;

public App()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();

    _viewViewModelTypeResolver = new ViewViewModelTypeResolver(this.GetType(), typeof(ViewModelBase));
}

//other methods are the same as Alexander's answer.
```

Thanks Alexander, your code was a great starting point for me.